# Передать JSON в PHP скрипт через AJAX запрос

Tags: php, ajax, json

Есть код, который формирует JSON

```
document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
```

Нужная часть справа от знака равно.

Как передать с помощью AJAX это дело в php-скрипт для сохранения в базу?
Просто как POST, в котором будет содержаться символы JSON, или есть другой более приемлемый способ?

Примерный код, который будет в JSON

---

```
{
   "class":"go.GraphLinksModel",
   "linkFromPortIdProperty":"fromPort",
   "linkToPortIdProperty":"toPort",
   "modelData":{
      "position":"-5 -149"
   },
   "nodeDataArray":[
      {
         "text":"Бизнес процесс",
         "figure":"Rect",
         "key":-1,
         "loc":"260 -80"
      },
      {
         "text":"Бизнес процесс",
         "figure":"Rect",
         "key":-2,
         "loc":"450 -30"
      },
      {
         "text":"Бизнес процесс",
         "figure":"Rect",
         "key":-3,
         "loc":"680 20"
      }
   ],
   "linkDataArray":[
      {
         "from":-1,
         "to":-2,
         "fromPort":"R",
         "toPort":"T",
         "points":[
            326.5,
            -80,
            336.5,
            -80,
            450,
            -80,
            450,
            -68.15,
            450,
            -56.3,
            450,
            -46.3
         ]
      },
      {
         "from":-1,
         "to":-2,
         "fromPort":"B",
         "toPort":"L",
         "points":[
            260,
            -63.69999999999999,
            260,
            -53.69999999999999,
            260,
            -30,
            316.75,
            -30,
            373.5,
            -30,
            383.5,
            -30
         ]
      },
      {
         "from":-2,
         "to":-3,
         "fromPort":"R",
         "toPort":"T",
         "points":[
            516.5,
            -30,
            526.5,
            -30,
            680,
            -30,
            680,
            -18.15,
            680,
            -6.300000000000001,
            680,
            3.6999999999999993
         ]
      },
      {
         "from":-2,
         "to":-3,
         "fromPort":"B",
         "toPort":"L",
         "points":[
            450,
            -13.699999999999996,
            450,
            -3.6999999999999957,
            450,
            20,
            526.75,
            20,
            603.5,
            20,
            613.5,
            20
         ]
      },
      {
         "from":-3,
         "to":-1,
         "fromPort":"B",
         "toPort":"L",
         "points":[
            680,
            36.3,
            680,
            46.3,
            183.5,
            46.3,
            183.5,
            -16.85,
            183.5,
            -80,
            193.5,
            -80
         ]
      },
      {
         "from":-3,
         "to":-1,
         "fromPort":"R",
         "toPort":"T",
         "points":[
            746.5,
            20,
            756.5,
            20,
            756.5,
            -106.3,
            508.25,
            -106.3,
            260,
            -106.3,
            260,
            -96.3
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: а чем POST   не угодил?

Comment: То есть просто в POST засовываешь и посылаешь скрипту? Тогда вопрос как это сделать в ajax? :-[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как передать с помощью AJAX это дело в php-скрипт для сохранения в базу? Просто как POST, в котором будет содержаться символы JSON, или есть другой более приемлемый способ?

Да, почему бы и нет. Это не очень нативно принимается со стороны PHP, но ничего сложного:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    ...
});
```

```
<?php
    $rawData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($rawData);
```

Не забудьте про обработку ошибок (в теле запроса может прийти не JSON или не прийти ничего).

Comment: А можете скинуть ссылку где бы это описывались?(плохо представляю это)я работал с JSON только на андроиде-брал данные из базы с помощью скрипта на сервере и послал JSON'оном в приложение.

Comment: @DarkVss, что нужно, кроме вышеописанного? Это, в общем, практически весь код.